# WaitGroup data sync guarantees

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization

[Go memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem), states the following:

> Programs that modify data being simultaneously accessed by multiple goroutines must serialize such access. To serialize access, **protect the data with channel operations or other synchronization primitives such as those in the sync and sync/atomic packages**.

Sadly, the documentation doesn't specify what `synchronization primitive` they relate to.

My question, is `WaitGroup` included in those `synchronization primitives`?

According to the above statement, in the following code, `done` might never be seen as true:

```
var a string
var done bool

func setup() {
    a = "hello, world"
    done = true
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    for !done {
    }
    print(a)
}
```

Does WaitGroup guarantees that once `waitgroup.Wait()` was called, values written in the group's goroutines execution to shared memory will be seen with the most updated values?

In other words, **is the following code guaranteed to print "hello"**? ([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zD_V3wxhD9N))

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

var a string = "start"
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func hello() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() { 
        a = "hello" 
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    print(a)
}

func main() {
    hello()
}
```

Comment: Yes, `WaitGroup` counts as a synchronization primitive, it wouldn't work if it didn't.

Comment: Yes of course. If it wouldn't the documentation of sync.WaitGroup would contain a sentence like "WaitGroup is a scam and doesn't work as documented; it's here because we thought it might be funny."

Comment: @Volker "doesn't work as documented" - where is it documented?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to your questions are all: **yes**. `WaitGroup` is a synchronization primitive which is why it is in the `sync` package.  The call to `Wait()` guarantees that you will see the correct value of `a`.  The code is guaranteed to print "hello".

There's not much else to say.